# "503 Service Unavailable" error in "yum update all" command

Tags: centos, yum

I am working on CentOS 6.4. I have setup a local repository using apache server. The path of the local repository is /var/www/html.

The etc/yum.conf file has a proxy server mentioned through "proxy=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080"

when I execute the command "yum update all". I get the following error:

> http://local.repo.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.3.2.0/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 503
>   Service Unavailable"

I am able to browse to this .xml file from other machines in the network. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue on your local repo. Can you post the permissions of files/directories under /var/www/html ?

Comment: There are huge number of folders and files under various directories under /var/www/html. Following is the result  on repomd.xml                            -rw-r--r-- 1 ambari-qa users 2997 Oct  1 05:29 repomd.xml

Comment: Is the network/IP of that machine authorised to make requests to that proxy?

Comment: I can confirm that the this machine is authorized to access the proxy. I think YUM is trying to access local.repo.com through proxy and it doesn't find it. But I am not sure.

Comment: I think your repo file is not correct. Please post this one also

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue. The problem was with the Apache Server, which was set up to serve as local repository. Even though I was able to ping the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)(local.repo.com) of the server, it seems that Yum was not able to reach the server server through (http://local.repo.com) "http" protocol. What I observed was this:

1) The etc/host file had an IP-FQDN mapping for local.repo.com

2) The Apache server had the following entry in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost local.repo.com:80>
        ServerName local.repo.com
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```

Since I could not figure out why Yum couldn't access the local repo through HTTP protocol i.e.; (http://local.repo.com), I did the following:

1) removed the above lines from httpd.conf file

2) In all the .repo files, mentioned the IP address instead of FQDN.

3) I did not remove IP-FQDN mapping for local.repo.com from the /etc/hosts file

4) In the /etc/yum.conf file, I mentioned the following

> proxy=http://Proxy_Server_Ip_Address:8080
>
> no_proxy="IP_Address_of_local_repo_server"

(Please note that the above steps, fixed the issue I was failing. There could be more proper answer to this problem).